# What work had the humans reinventing the space flight during war (having the wormholes all the time)?

Tags: story-identification

I heard recommendation (on some of TWiT shows before Christmas) of a story in which humans were at war (I don't remember whether it was as home war or war with aliens) and they resurrected/woken up general. He reintroduced forgotten space flight to win the war but as he was the older he become a supreme commander which many people didn't like (and there was a politics subplot).

Can anyone identify a story?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That sounds like the [Lost Fleet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Lost_Fleet) series by Jack Campbell.

Comment: Yeah, in the http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Lost_Fleet series the hero is retrieved from a lost statis pod\escape pod and prevents the total destruction of his sides fleet by using wormholes which had been abandoned in favor of artificial gateways. He also reintroduces his species to the concept of tactics and strategy since all the current version of warfare consists of blind suicide charges. Amusing series that tries to be hard sci-fi (maybe medium sci-fi) but its clear the author doesn't fully understand what he's trying to do.

Answer (score 5):

This could be a reference to [Pandoras Star](http://www.peterfhamilton.co.uk/index.php?page=Pandora_s_Star)/[Judas Unchained](http://www.peterfhamilton.co.uk/index.php?page=Judas_Unchained) by [Peter F Hamilton](http://www.peterfhamilton.co.uk/).

There's a strong political subplot in this story, as well as the routine use of ressurection/rejuvenation technologies, and one of the central characters is an old astronaut.

> The series opens with the landing on Mars of first manned trip to the red planet, only to have the glory of the feat undermined by an experimental wormhole from a physics lab in California. The pilot of the lander, and #3 to set foot on Mars, is Wilson Kime (sp?).

Within the story, humankind has settled hundreds of worlds, all connected by wormhole. When the events of the story occur, the first intersellar space craft is built to investigate.

> The guy behind the building of the ship, Nigel Sheldon, selects Wilson to be the captain of the ship, based on his previous experience. Actions of saboteur on the ship result in an agressive alien species being freed from a stellar prison, resulting in war.

Comment: After reading both books I have too admit that The Lost Fleet better suited the description ad I remembered it.