# Book about a guy who can create portals, uses the sun to destroy missiles

Tags: story-identification, books

I read a book years ago about a guy that creates portals that can be directed to source and destination.  He used it to tie one end to the sun and used the other end to destroy missiles.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  When was "years ago?"  You might want to check out the [suggestions](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/101407) for asking good story-id questions.

Comment: "Years ago" does not tell is anything. Was it 2-3 years ago? Was it 10 years ago? was it 40 years ago? A time period helps narrow down the possibilities... Also, was it new when you read it? or a book from a used book store or library that might have been 20 years older when you read it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/2160/what-work-had-the-humans-reinventing-the-space-flight-during-war-having-the-wor, among others

Answer (score 3):

That sounds vaguely like the [Commonwealth saga](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commonwealth_Saga) books by Peter Hamilton, starting with Pandora's Star (2004) and Judas Unchained (2005).

The series is set centuries after Nigel Sheldon and Ozzie Isaacs first developed wormhole technology (demonstrated when they greet the first astronauts to land on Mars). The wormholes are later anchored to stations on distant planets, allowing human society to spread and create the Commonwealth. Eventually humans encounter the hostile Prime species and there is much use of wormhole technology to deliver munitions and troops, as well as putting one end of a wormhole into a star and projecting the other end at the enemy.

Comment: Agreed, it is so vague and so little is remembered, that the CS-being-very-poorly-remembered was my first thought as well.

Comment: Except that in the Commonwealth saga no wormhole is ever connected to a star. That point is different.

Comment: @PabloH I could be misremembering. I know I've read some novel where that's done, and I know they do something similar in one of the Void novels.